# Apache Pig: Extra query parameters from web log

Tags: apache-pig, amazon-cloudfront

I am working on analyzing AWS CloudFront access logs.

I have the code to load the lines of the file

```
    raw_logs2 =LOAD 'file:///home/ec2-user/ENWRZAC68E00M.2011-02-28-18.72jA8eGh'
  USING PigStorage('\t')
  AS (
    date: chararray, time: chararray, x_edge_location: chararray, sc_bytes: int,
    c_ip: chararray, cs_method: chararray, cs_host: chararray, cs_uri_stem: chararray,
    sc_status: chararray, cs_referer: chararray, cs_user_agent:chararray, cs_uri_query: chararray
  );
```

Now I am trying to parse the query string parameters(name/value pairs):

```
p=searchresults&s=homesforsale&gad=&gci=FOUNTAIN%2520VALLEY&gst=CA&gzi=&k=fountainvalleyca&ts=1298918206&
```

How can I add an additional columns to my raw_logs2 table for the values of p,s and gci in the query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One quick way to do it is to use [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.0/piglatin_ref2.html#REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL):

```
raw_logs = 
  GENERATE
    *, 
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(cs_uri_query, 'p=(.+?)&s=(.+?)&.+?gci=(.+?)&.+?')) 
      AS (p:CHARARRAY, s:CHARARRAY, gci:CHARARRAY);`
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Romain.  I expanded on the sample and got this:
`code` raw_logs = 
  GENERATE
    *, 
    FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(cs_uri_query, 'p=(.+?)&s=(.+?)&w=(.+?)&h=(.+?)&ad=(.+?)&gad=(.+?)&gci=(.+?)&gst=(.+?)&gzi=(.+?)&kw=(.+?)&.+?')) 
      AS (p:CHARARRAY, s:CHARARRAY, w:CHARARRAY, h:CHARARRAY, ad:CHARARRAY, gad:CHARARRAY, gci:CHARARRAY, gst:CHARARRAY, gzi:CHARARRAY, kw:CHARARRAY);`/code`
I am using pig 0.6.0 and get an error that it got generate and it expected something else.  How does the call know that cs_uri_query came from when I loaded raw_logs2 from my log file.

Comment: I updated to 0.8.0 and made the change to add a FOREACH before it and it works great. Thanks.