# How to parse through a column in Pig to create additional columns

Tags: regex, parsing, apache-pig

New Apache Pig user here. I basically have data in a format and need to split this into 6 columns to create my desired schema and then load into Pig for my existing script to run.

Sorry if the format below is untidy, i cant upload a picture due to reputation score.

Existing format has 3 columns
**User-Equipment    values::key:bytearray   values:value:bytearray**
user1-mobile    20130306-AC 9
user1-mobile    20130306-AT 21
user2-laptop    20130306-BC 0

Required format:
**User       Equipment  Date    Type    "Count or Time"   Value**

user1   mobile  20130306    A       C             9

user1   mobile  20130306    A       T             21

Any suggestions on how to ge this done? IS there a regex I need to write?
The tricky thing here is all the columns have a delimiter (-) between them except "Type" and column "C or T"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a common delimiter I can think of two possibilities:

1. You could implement your own LoadFunc as explained here: http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449302641/load_and_store_funcs.html
2. You could use [REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.8.1/piglatin_ref2.html#REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL) as explained here: [Apache Pig: Extra query parameters from web log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305086/apache-pig-extra-query-parameters-from-web-log)

Here you go for 2.:

```
A = LOAD 'abc.txt' AS (line:CHARARRAY);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE FLATTEN(REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(line, '^(.+?)\\-(.+?)\\s(.+?)\\-(.)(.)\\s(.+)$')) AS (User:CHARARRAY,Equipment:CHARARRAY,Date:CHARARRAY,Type:CHARARRAY,CountorTime:CHARARRAY,Value:CHARARRAY);
```